# Add an administrative edit checkbox for mods that are acting in accord with some meta topic

Tags: feature-request, edits, serial-edits

A check-box should be available to mods to allow them to do useful manual retagging (the type that is not possible to do automatically, like separate the volume tag into logical-drive and audio tags on SU) without flooding the front page.

The check-box should be associated with a text field or something that would hold the meta post that the mod is acting in accord with. This would generate a list on that post with all the posts that have been edited in accordance with the meta post.

This would accomplish three objectives:

1. Not flood the front page when doing these types of edits
2. Create an easy way for the edits relating to a meta post to be tracked
3. Allow for some review over the process should a user want to look it over for some reason (I.e. a mod cannot do anything they want, and not have it show up anywhere. I don't anticipate this being a problem, but it can't hurt either)

Thoughts?

Comment: +1 **Yes**, I'd rather want a number next to review than a full page of edits when these are necessary; or some other way to link to this page, such that it gets viewed *as much as /review or /tools* but not more than that. As a side suggestion, it might be useful to give this out to 20k reputation users as well; as we don't want to burden the moderators alone and there are high reputation users up for this. **For SO users:** Please note that other sites don't have the interesting tab and thus show the questions ordered by answers and edit bumps...

Comment: @Random Not a dupe as this is 1) mod only 2) tied to meta posts with a way for review.